# Overlap of two files in Linux or respective replacement of lines from file1 with lines from file2

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am a new Linux user and I still haven't figured out how to use it, I solved the problem in very ugly way but I am sure it can be solved by some clever use of `sed` or `awk`.
Problem is a bit hard to explain but it concerns with how to overlap two text files which are formatted by certain rules.

**Problem 1:**

Rules: file1 has some lines which equal to string "`custom`", those lines have to be replaced by the lines which exist in `file2` RESPECTIVELY, so first time "`custom`" occurs in `file1`, first line of `file2` will be put instead of line which had "`custom`" in file2, second time "`custom`" occurs in file1 it needs to be replaced by second line of file2 etc.
Also number of occurrences of "`custom`" lines in `file1` equals the number of lines in `file2`.

**Example:**

File1:

```
line1
line2
custom
line4
custom
line6
```

File2:

```
line3
line5
```

output:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

One way of solving this is maybe to search for first occurrence of `custom`, replace it by first line in `file2`, delete first line from `file2`, search for next occurrence of custom, take first line in `file2`, delete it and so on. I am sure much better way exists with sed/grep/awk.

**Problem 2:**

User of the code actually needs to specify file2 as I tell him, so maybe if the problem was formulated like this it would be easier to solve:

These are the rules: both file1 and file2 now have equal number of lines.
Some of the lines in file1 equal to string "custom" as in previous problem.
File2 has empty lines at places where lines in file1 don't equal to "custom", so I literally want to paste file2 over file1 and only overwrite lines with "custom".

file 1 looks like this:

```
line1                          
custom  
line3   
custom
line5
```

file 2 is:

```
/n
line2
/n
line4
/n
```

/n stands for empty line, output is

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Also I'd like output of the solution to overwrite file1 (I reckon I can do it by `solution >> file1`)

I'd like solutions for both problems and explanation what did the commands you used actualy did.

I actually have only 1-3 lines in file1 for current version of the code, so I solved the issue with a lot of if-else scenarios by heading and tailing lines in file2, but I am certain something more elegant is possible.

**BONUS question:**

I firstly stored contents of lines in file1 as separate variables (`$line1`, `$line2` etc), and almost solved the problem with `awk`, but it didn't want to accept `$var` because of the `''` quotes, and also it didn't work with `""` quotes.
I saw that sed can do powerful things but can it be run with pattern saved in string variable? I tried calling `sed` with `""` and `$var` worked, but will it always work? I tried the same with awk and it broke.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: **and almost solved the problem with awk**: Can you show your solution in question

Comment: Should the second example not have two `line3` lines?

Comment: Sorry, it's something I found online and gave up when it didn't work. I edited problem 2.

Comment: My solution was 39 lines long, lines in file1 represent lists (sequnces of number like 1 2 3 4 5) of sweep points I want my simulation to do, if user specified 2D or 3D sweep then the file will have 2 or 3 lines, he can specify range of his sweep through a flag in the script (which will do seq '' of his entry), but if he puts that the value of the flag is "custom" then he has to specify a file where he stored his custom sweep points.

Comment: File1 basicaly measures whether I have 1D,2D or 3D simulation and if some line equals to custom then it searches for those custom lists in file2, since lines in file1 can be 1, 2 or 3 there are theoretically 8 possible cases what the user wanted, so I wrote 39 lines which solves those cases.

Comment: Before doing those 39 lines I realized that the problem could've been solved if I could overlap file2 in places where file1 has "custom", but I couldn't find online solution and this is my very first script in bash so I just did the brute force solution.

Comment: I really like bash so far, specially because of load of things it can do with files, but I think I still have to go through some tutorials for bash more carefully and figure out how awk/sed/grep/diff and similar functions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

for the first problem, here is a simple solution with getline, generally considered dangerous, but if you are immune to the side effects there is no harm.

```
$ awk '/custom/{getline < "file2"; print; next} 1' file1

line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

for the second case, it might be easier to combine the files with some unused char first and then let awk pick the right choice.

```
$ paste -d~ file2 file1 | awk -F~ '{print $1==""?$2:$1}'

line1
line2
line3
line3
line4
```

Comment: It work perfectly, you just reduced 39 lines in my code down to one line. I spent ages last night googling for the solution. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: Can you please check if you have elegant answer to other question I posted (36317896). I realized that I didn't make file1 from this problem properly.